# (xyz) | select propertyA vs (xyz).propertyA in PowerShell vcenterevent vs aduser

Tags: powershell, select, vmware, snapshot

I am a beginner at Powershell. I am writing a script but not getting proper formatted output on particular section

@{N='Created By';E={Get-ADUser -Identity (((Get-VIEvent -Entity $*.VM -Types Info -start $*.Created.AddMinutes(-1) -Finish $*.Created.AddHours(1) -MaxSamples ([int]::MaxValue) | Where  {$*.FullFormattedMessage -match 'Create virtual machine snapshot'-and ($_.Username -notlike 'XY\svc_veeam')}).username).Trim('XY\     ')).name}},

No output in cell

@{N='Created By';E={Get-ADUser -Identity (((Get-VIEvent -Entity $*.VM -Types Info -start $*.Created.AddMinutes(-1) -Finish $*.Created.AddHours(1) -MaxSamples ([int]::MaxValue) | Where  {$*.FullFormattedMessage -match 'Create virtual machine snapshot'-and ($_.Username -notlike 'XY\svc_veeam')}).username).Trim('XY\     '))| select name}},

Getting
@{name=firstname lastname}

But I need in the cell firstname  lastname.

I hope you can understand my problem.

The whole program works fine but this formate issue crating problem. I do not want to create variable and other as creating variable between formatting seems not possible.

I would request to check the above 2 lines and suggest.

Comment: Remove `.name` at the very end (the target expression is a _string_ returned by `String.Trim()`, it won't have a `name` property)

Comment: Then you need an extra set of `(...)` around the whole `Get-ADUser` statement (`(Get-ADUser ...).Name`)

Comment: if i remove .name

@{N='Created By'....................ke 'XY\svc_veeam')}).username).Trim('XY\ '))},


then output will be all get-ADuser fields

how to remove exact same string from the output. 

I get output form from Get-VIEvent like XY\ABCD user it works fine in the case but if the user name contains XY then get-ADuser unable to find it as XY from login ID removed 
XY\ABCD - OK XY\ABXY not able to find user as  Get-ADuser -Identity works on username not on domain\username.

Comment: Then you need an extra set of (...) around the whole Get-ADUser statement ((Get-ADUser ...).Name)... Did the same but no output